# How to find the relations between tables in Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to know the relationships between the tables in a database in Microsoft SQL Server 2008. Number of tables is around 100.

How to draw the ER diagram?

Comment: If your database is normalized means well design with relationship. You just drag and drop table and Diagram automatically fetches the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can create ER Database Diagrams from SQL Server Management Studio by doing this:

1. *SQL Server Management Studio* → *Object Explorer* → *Databases* → *Database Node* (The node which will have your database name).
2. Under your database node you will find *Database Diagrams* along with Tables, Views etc.
3. Right click on *Database Diagrams* and select new database diagram; it should launch a wizard to generate the *Database Diagram* (which contains all tables along with their keys and relationships.

You can find more details by reading this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224825%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Source [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1790223.aspx?Making%20ER%20Diagram%20from%20SQL%20Server%202008%20Database).